# Parallelise rsync using GNU Parallel

Tags: linux, rhel, rsync, gnu-parallel

I have been using a `rsync` script to synchronize data at one host with the data at another host. The data has numerous small-sized files that contribute to almost 1.2TB.

In order to sync those files, I have been using `rsync` command as follows:

```
rsync -avzm --stats --human-readable --include-from proj.lst /data/projects REMOTEHOST:/data/
```

The contents of proj.lst are as follows:

```
+ proj1
+ proj1/*
+ proj1/*/*
+ proj1/*/*/*.tar
+ proj1/*/*/*.pdf
+ proj2
+ proj2/*
+ proj2/*/*
+ proj2/*/*/*.tar
+ proj2/*/*/*.pdf
...
...
...
- *
```

As a test, I picked up two of those projects (8.5GB of data) and executed the command above. Being a sequential process, it took 14 minutes and 58 seconds to complete. So, for 1.2TB of data, it would take several hours.

If I would could have multiple `rsync` processes in parallel (using `&`, `xargs` or `parallel`), it would save me time.

I tried with below command with `parallel` (after `cd`ing to the source directory) and it took 12 minutes 37 seconds to execute:

```
parallel --will-cite -j 5 rsync -avzm --stats --human-readable {} REMOTEHOST:/data/ ::: .
```

This should have taken 5 times less time, but it didn't. I think, I'm going wrong somewhere.

How can I run multiple `rsync` processes in order to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Are you limited by network bandwidth? Disk iops? Disk bandwidth?

Comment: If possible, we would want to use 50% of total bandwidth. But, parallelising multiple `rsync`s is our first priority.

Comment: Can you let us know your: Network bandwidth, disk iops, disk bandwidth, and the bandwidth actually used?

Comment: In fact, I do not know about above parameters. For the time being, we can neglect the optimization part. Multiple `rsync`s in parallel is the primary focus now.

Comment: No point in going parallel if the limitation isn't the CPU. It can/will even make matters worse (conflicting disk arm movements on source or target disk).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Following steps did the job for me:

1. Run the `rsync --dry-run` first in order to get the list of files those would be affected.

```
$ rsync -avzm --stats --safe-links --ignore-existing --dry-run \
    --human-readable /data/projects REMOTE-HOST:/data/ > /tmp/transfer.log
```

2. I fed the output of `cat transfer.log` to `parallel` in order to run 5 `rsync`s in parallel, as follows:

```
$ cat /tmp/transfer.log | \
    parallel --will-cite -j 5 rsync -avzm --relative \
      --stats --safe-links --ignore-existing \
      --human-readable {} REMOTE-HOST:/data/ > result.log
```

Here, `--relative` option ([link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195458/absolute-path-in-rsync-dry-run-statistics)) ensured that the directory structure for the affected files, at the source and destination, remains the same (inside `/data/` directory), so the command must be run in the source folder (in example, `/data/projects`).

Comment: That would do an rsync per file. It would probably be more efficient to split up the whole file list using `split` and feed those filenames to parallel. Then use rsync's `--files-from` to get the filenames out of each file and sync them.
rm backups.*
    split -l 3000 backup.list backups.
    
    ls backups.* | parallel --line-buffer --verbose -j 5 rsync --progress -av --files-from {} /LOCAL/PARENT/PATH/  REMOTE_HOST:REMOTE_PATH/

Comment: On newer versions of rsync (3.1.0+), you can use `--info=name` in place of `-v`, and you'll get just the names of the files and directories.  You may want to use --protect-args to the 'inner' transferring rsync too if any files might have spaces or shell metacharacters in them.

Answer (score 28):

I would strongly discourage anybody from using the accepted answer, a better solution is to crawl the top level directory and launch a proportional number of rsync operations.

I have a large zfs volume and my source was a cifs mount. Both are linked with 10G, and in some benchmarks can saturate the link. Performance was evaluated using `zpool iostat 1`.

The source drive was mounted like:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=,password= //static_ip/70tb /mnt/Datahoarder_Mount/ -o vers=3.0
```

Using a single `rsync` process:

```
rsync -h -v -r -P -t /mnt/Datahoarder_Mount/ /StoragePod
```

the io meter reads:

```
StoragePod  30.0T   144T      0  1.61K      0   130M
StoragePod  30.0T   144T      0  1.61K      0   130M
StoragePod  30.0T   144T      0  1.62K      0   130M
```

This in synthetic benchmarks (crystal disk), performance for sequential write approaches 900 MB/s which means the link is saturated. 130MB/s is not very good, and the difference between waiting a weekend and two weeks.

So, I built the file list and tried to run the sync again (I have a 64 core machine):

```
cat /home/misha/Desktop/rsync_logs_syncs/Datahoarder_Mount.log | parallel --will-cite -j 16 rsync -avzm --relative --stats --safe-links --size-only --human-readable {} /StoragePod/ > /home/misha/Desktop/rsync_logs_syncs/Datahoarder_Mount_result.log
```

and it had the same performance!

```
StoragePod  29.9T   144T      0  1.63K      0   130M
StoragePod  29.9T   144T      0  1.62K      0   130M
StoragePod  29.9T   144T      0  1.56K      0   129M
```

As an alternative I simply ran rsync on the root folders:

```
rsync -h -v -r -P -t /mnt/Datahoarder_Mount/Mikhail/Marcello_zinc_bone /StoragePod/Marcello_zinc_bone
rsync -h -v -r -P -t /mnt/Datahoarder_Mount/Mikhail/fibroblast_growth /StoragePod/fibroblast_growth
rsync -h -v -r -P -t /mnt/Datahoarder_Mount/Mikhail/QDIC /StoragePod/QDIC
rsync -h -v -r -P -t /mnt/Datahoarder_Mount/Mikhail/sexy_dps_cell /StoragePod/sexy_dps_cell
```

This actually boosted performance:

```
StoragePod  30.1T   144T     13  3.66K   112K   343M
StoragePod  30.1T   144T     24  5.11K   184K   469M
StoragePod  30.1T   144T     25  4.30K   196K   373M
```

In conclusion, as @Sandip Bhattacharya brought up, write a small script to get the directories and parallel that. Alternatively, pass a file list to rsync. But don't create new instances for each file.

Answer (score 22):

I personally use this simple one:

```
\ls -1 | parallel rsync -a {} /destination/directory/
```

Which only is useful when you have more than a few non-near-empty directories, else you'll end up having almost every `rsync` terminating and the last one doing all the job alone.

Note the backslash before `ls` which causes aliases to be skipped. Thus, ensuring that the output is as desired.

Comment: How does this deal with filenames with (for example) `\n` in them?

Comment: @TomHale hopefully it reaches through time and space to beat the crud out of the person who made such a file...

Comment: @RonJohn absolutely agree

Answer (score 8):

A tested way to do the parallelized rsync is:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_examples.html#example-parallelizing-rsync

> rsync is a great tool, but sometimes it will not fill up the available bandwidth. This is often a problem when copying several big files over high speed connections.
>
> The following will start one rsync per big file in src-dir to dest-dir
> on the server fooserver:
>
> ```
> cd src-dir; find . -type f -size +100000 | \
> parallel -v ssh fooserver mkdir -p /dest-dir/{//}\; \
>   rsync -s -Havessh {} fooserver:/dest-dir/{}
> ```
>
> The directories created may end up with wrong permissions and smaller files are not being transferred. To fix those run rsync a final time:
>
> ```
> rsync -Havessh src-dir/ fooserver:/dest-dir/
> ```

> If you are unable to
> push data, but need to pull them and the files are called digits.png
> (e.g. 000000.png) you might be able to do:
>
> ```
> seq -w 0 99 | parallel rsync -Havessh fooserver:src/*{}.png destdir/
> ```

Comment: cat files | parallel -v ssh fooserver mkdir -p /dest-dir/{//}\; rsync -s -Havessh {} fooserver:/dest-dir/{}

Comment: This has a newer version at https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Parallelizing-rsync, using one pass for all files and `parallel -j10` (where 10 is the number of parallel jobs).

Answer (score 4):

For multi destination syncs, I am using

```
parallel rsync -avi /path/to/source ::: host1: host2: host3:
```

Hint: All ssh connections are established with public keys in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 3):

A more recent option to consider is using [Fpsync](http://www.fpart.org/fpsync/), which wraps rsync but should be more efficient than launching an rsync process-per-file because it operates on "partitions" -- batches of files. It also starts copying immediately -- while still walking the directory tree -- instead of waiting for the crawl to finish.

Here's an example:

```
fpsync -vvv -o '-avm --numeric-ids --safe-links' -n 10 <SOURCE PATH> <DEST PATH>
```

I wish it provided nicer output... you actually get no output without at least specifying `-v`, but it does seem to maximize throughput for transfers.

Here's the full manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/fpsync.1.html

Answer (score 2):

I always google for parallel rsync as I always forget the full command, but no solution worked for me as I wanted - either it includes multiple steps or needs to install `parallel`. I ended up using this one-liner to sync multiple folders:

```
find dir/ -type d|xargs -P 5 -I % sh -c 'rsync -a --delete --bwlimit=50000 $(echo dir/%/ host:/dir/%/)'
```

`-P 5` is the amount of processes you want to spawn - use 0 for unlimited (obviously not recommended).

`--bwlimit` to avoid using all bandwidth.

`-I %` argument provided by find (directory found in `dir/`)

`$(echo dir/%/ host:/dir/%/)` - prints source and destination directories which are read by rsync as arguments. % is replaced by `xargs` with directory name found by `find`.

Let's assume I have two directories in `/home`: `dir1` and `dir2`. I run `find /home -type d|xargs -P 5 -I % sh -c 'rsync -a --delete --bwlimit=50000 $(echo /home/%/ host:/home/%/)'`. So rsync command will run as two processes (two processes because `/home` has two directories) with following arguments:

```
rsync -a --delete --bwlimit=50000 /home/dir1/ host:/home/dir1/
rsync -a --delete --bwlimit=50000 /home/dir1/ host:/home/dir1/
```

Comment: The `$(echo ...)` part seems to be unnecessary. `xargs` is already templating that part anyways.

Comment: Ok, I just tried this solution and it is very close, but not quite yet. `find` will find all the directories in a recursive manner, meaning that using `rsync` with `-a` will produce jobs that overlap (because `xargs` will produce a job for each each level of the directory tree). To fix that is easy, one just need to add `--no-r -d` to the `rsync` command. Also, it is very likely that directory creation on the destination has to be handled _a priori_.

Comment: This is broken if any file has a space or other special character in the name - add `-print0` to the find, `-0` to the xargs, and appropriate quotes  where the file substitutions are. Also need to do `-depth 1` on the find to just go 1 level down (so no clashes)

Answer (score 0):

```
SRC="mysrc"
DST="mydst"
NUM_THREADS="4"  # Adjust this value based on your system's resources

# Create a list of files to transfer, excluding directories
find "$SRC" -type f -exec realpath --relative-to="$SRC" '{}' \; > files_to_transfer.txt

# Create a list of directories to transfer
find "$SRC" -type d -exec realpath --relative-to="$SRC" '{}' \; > dirs_to_create.txt

# Create directories in the destination
cat dirs_to_create.txt | while read -r dir; do mkdir -p "$DST/$dir"; done

# Use GNU Parallel to run multiple rsync instances in parallel
cat files_to_transfer.txt | parallel -j "$NUM_THREADS" --quote rsync -av "$SRC"/{} "$DST"/{}
```

This assumes the target is mounted somehow. If not, you'll need to replace the "mkdir -p" line with something else.

```
cat dirs_to_create.txt | while read -r dir; do mkdir -p "$DST/$dir"; done
```

could be replaced with

```
cat dirs_to_create.txt | while read -r dir; do ssh $REMOTE_HOST "mkdir -p \"$DST/$dir\""; done
```

for example. If there are many many dirs this maybe should be transferred as a file and executed on the remote end.