# Absolute path in rsync dry-run statistics

Tags: rsync

I have executed following command in order to get the list of files that would be transferred to remote server if `rsync` is executed:

`rsync -avzm --stats --safe-links --ignore-existing --dry-run --human-readable /tmp/test REMOTE-HOST:/tmp/data/ >> /tmp/transfer.log`

In order to fetch only the list of files (all are PDFs), I executed following command:

`grep 'pdf$' transfer.log > files.txt`

Where I could not see the absolute paths of the files:

```
test/2103/0E/210321449902_NR_1/210321449902-1-A4-NB.pdf
test/2103/0E/210321481320_NR_1/210321481320.AKPML.pdf
test/2103/0E/210321779915_NR_1/210321779915-1-A4-NB.pdf
test/2103/0E/210321959975_NR_1/210321959975-01-A4-NB.pdf
```

What option should be used in order to get absolute paths of the files when `rsync` dry-run is performed?

I need to use that list of files so that I can `cat` the file list and execute multiple `rsync`s using GNU `parallel`. (as in [THIS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189878/parallelise-rsync-using-gnu-parallel) question)

Comment: Use the `-R` or `--relative` option.

Comment: Odd that one has to specify `--relative` to get absolute paths, but it works.  Suggest you post it as an answer, @fd0.

Comment: `-R` is a really bad idea in general. It (fundamentally) changes the *behaviour* of rsync, not the reporting.