# Speed up / avoid calculation of rsync file lists

Tags: rsync, backup

I use rsync 3.1.1 to keep in sync two discs, one of which is on the network and mounted as a samba share on `/mnt/ROUTER_WD_2TB/`. This is the source, with a speed of 30-40MB/s maximum due to network limitations. The other, the destination, is mounted locally (peak 110MB/s) and is `/mnt/BACKUP_HITACHI_2TB/`.

I use the following rsync command:

```
rsync  -haAXi --quiet --append-verify --delete /mnt/ROUTER_WD_2TB/* /mnt/BACKUP_HITACHI_2TB/.
```

The disks contain *many* files, most of them small.

The problem is that rsync takes quite a long time (10-20m) *before* starting to move any files, I guess because it has to compute file lists for a very large number of small files. During this period, the newtwork utilization sits at a low 200-500KB/s, while when transferring files the speed is about 40MB/s.

It usually happens that rsync takes about 15m to finally find something it has to copy, then takes 5 seconds to copy it, then continues checking for some other files to copy for another 5 minutes. All in all, a 5 second file copy ends up lasting 20 minutes!

Is there any measure I could take to avoid this long period prior to copying the files, other than excluding folders? Any kind of "cache" I can implement so that rsync does not have to rebuild all the file list from scratch?

Comment: Have you tried a solution from this thread? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189878/parallelise-rsync-using-gnu-parallel

Comment: @UVV I have not done that. i may do that, however 1) rsync already does not seem to use a full core in my case, for some reason (= I'm unsure if I'm CPU limited or if the limitation lies elsewhere) and 2) This is only on a dual-core CPU, so even if the improvement was 2X, there would still be a large margin for improvement.

Comment: Yeah this seems crazy to me, why is rsync so slow at this? Even with "--size-only" rsync seems to take forever to build its incremental file list. Why? I can manually check the file sizes and determine which ones have changed much faster! What is it wasting so much time doing, and how do I turn these fancy features off? EDIT: Ah, never mind, I had the 'c' flag set by accident. Without the checksums it is very fast at this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as `rsync` is concerned you're copying between two local file trees, so it disables most of its optimisations (including its delta algorithm for which it is famous). If you can run an `rsync` on your remote server (so you get a true client-server scenario across your network) you'll gain a significant amount of traction.

Nevertheless here are other options to consider

1. Copying without worrying about deleting old files. This may allow you to perform a faster transfer more often, and relegate the slower cleanup to say, just once a day:

   ```
   cp -au /mnt/ROUTER_WD_2TB/. /mnt/BACKUP_HITACHI_2TB/
   ```
2. Use a variation of `rsync`'s default deletion algorithm to avoid building a full list of files before the transfer:

   ```
   rsync -haAXi --quiet --delete --delete-during /mnt/ROUTER_WD_2TB/ /mnt/BACKUP_HITACHI_2TB/
   ```
3. Split the top-level directories into separate tasks and run them in parallel. You may find that if you're disk IO-bound then this won't really help, and for spinning platters it almost certainly will make things worse.

   ```
   for d in /mnt/ROUTER_WD_2TB/*
   do
       rsync -haAXi --quiet --delete --delete-during "$d" /mnt/BACKUP_HITACHI_2TB/ >"/tmp/rsync.${d/*\/}.log" 2>&1 &
   done
   wait
   cat /tmp/rsync.*.log
   rm -f /tmp/rsync.*.log
   ```

If none of these suggestions helps then it would be worth adding another `--verbose` to `rsync` to see what it is doing. I suspect it's rattling through all the unchanged files, and if you have enough files this simply takes a long time.

Comment: `--delete --delete-during` didn't do it for me — that still sent an incremental file list — but `--delete --delete-before` went straight to: `building file list`, which seems like major progress. I think.

Comment: No, that's backwards, I'm afraid. If you use `--delete-before`, then`rsync` performs two passes across the file tree: one for deletions and the next for copying.

Comment: Thanks. In that case...any way to avoid building the incremental file list?

Comment: @mlissner it depends on several different factors. The biggest one by far is whether you're doing local-to-local or local-to-remote copying.

Comment: It's all local to local for me, though one of the locals is a USB disk?

Comment: `--delete-during` implies `--delete`.