# poor mans backup with find and parallel compression

Tags: find, backup, multithreading, bzip2

I'm planning to backup the `/home` folder of my Kubuntu box to an external drive.

In order to speed up the process I consider zipping large files (individually) so that writing them is faster. I also want to do the zipping/copying in multiple threads so that the resources of the box are better used. I thought of something like this:

```
find /home/ -exec sh -c 'bzip2 "$1" "/path/to/target/$1.bz2"&' find-sh {} \;
```

On the other hand I want to avoid to spawn thousands of processes, what this script most likely will do.

What is the best way to combine `find` and `bzip2` so that the latter runs in parallel with a limited number of threads?

Comment: Consider the use of `rsync` and `parallel` together.

Comment: @steve do you mean something like this: `find /home/ -exec sh -c 'parallel  rsync --compress ... "$1" /path/to/target/$1.gz' find-sh {} \;`?

Comment: I was thinking of the answers shown at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189878/parallelise-rsync-using-gnu-parallel

Comment: xz has a better compression/time tradeoff than bzip2. Consider zipping files together, you'll get better compression. And I strongly recommend using a robust tool for backups rather than cobbling up your own. Duplicity is pretty simple to use and does compressed incremental backups, optionally encrypted.

Comment: @Gilles does Duplicity also use more than one core of my cpu? and can I backut to alocal folder like /mnt/removableDisk/backup?

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with starting a few `tar` jobs by hand...